# Python - How to populate a dictionary of lists adhering to a nested hierarchy?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm close to being able to populate a dictionary of lists given 2 other lists and another dictionary, but still do not have the right output.

Min reproducible example of what I'm working with:

```
list1 = ['db1', 'db2']
list2 = ['tbl1', 'tbl2', 'tbl3']

other_dict = {
  'DICT':{
    'db1':{
      'tbl1':{}
    },
    'db2': {
      'tbl2':{},
      'tbl3':{},
      'tbl4':{}
    }
  }
}
```

My code should essentially create a new dictionary with the same hierarchy as `other_dict` but with only the items listed in `list1` and `list2`. So as per the above example, the output should be:

```
{
 'db1': ['tbl1'],
 'db2': ['tbl2', 'tbl3']
}
```

What I have so far and have tried is:

```
my_dict = dict((db, [tbl]) for db in list1 for tbl in list2 if tbl 
                in other_dict['DICT'][db])
```

This produces: `{'db1': ['tbl1'], 'db2': ['tbl3']}` and misses out on `tbl2`, I'm guessing because each key has to be unique.

How can I fix my code to account for adding multiple nested level items to a main level item when populating a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of the sublists is not significant, this is probably handled most-efficiently with set operations. You can just take the intersection between the keys of each sub dict and `list2`:

```
list1 = ['db1', 'db2']
list2 = ['tbl1', 'tbl2', 'tbl3']

other_dict = {
 'DICT':{
      'db1':{
       'tbl1':{}
      },
      'db2': {
       'tbl2':{},
       'tbl3':{},
       'tbl4':{}
      }
    }
}

d = {k: list(set(other_dict['DICT'][k]).intersection(list2)) for k in list1}
#{'db1': ['tbl1'], 'db2': ['tbl3', 'tbl2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
list1 = ['db1', 'db2']
list2 = ['tbl1', 'tbl2', 'tbl3']

other_dict = {
  'DICT':{
    'db1':{
      'tbl1':{}
    },
    'db2': {
      'tbl2':{},
      'tbl3':{},
      'tbl4':{}
    }
  }
}

other_dict2 = {}

for db in other_dict['DICT']:
    other_dict2[db] = []
    for key in other_dict['DICT'][db].keys():
        if key in list2:
            other_dict2[db].append(key)
```